# JavaScript - Array mapping with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays which starts off as this:

```
let days = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null];

const weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
```

Depending on what data I'm given, I want to map a new array with the corresponding weekday, but still keep it the same size array.

```
let numDays = ["0","2","4"]

let days = days.map(?)

days
> ['Sunday', null, 'Tuesday', null, 'Thursday', null, null]
```

I have attempted a conversion function which can convert `numDays` to its corresponding`weekdays`

```
const convert = function (c) {
  return weekdays[c];
}

numDays.map(convert)
> ['Sunday', 'Tuesday', 'Thursday']
```

But not sure how to retain the array size for the result I need.

Cheers!

Comment: `map` returns an array with the same size of the array you are executing it on. you can not simply use `map` for that.

Comment: I'm executing `map` on `days` which will give me the correct array size (7 elements). My question is figuring out how to use `numDays` as a reference index to replace the `weekdays` in `days`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the `days` variable to be `[null, null, null, null, null, null, null]`.

```js
const weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];

let numDays = ["0","2","4"];

var days = weekdays.map(function(day, index){
  if (numDays.indexOf(index.toString()) >= 0){
    return day;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
});

console.log(days);
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach might be easier than using `map`, you can use `forEach` to loop over the required indexes, look up the day and add them to your `days` array as required.

```js
const weekdays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
let numDays = ["0","2","4"]
let days = [null, null, null, null, null, null, null];
numDays.forEach(i=>days[i] = weekdays[i]);
console.log(days);
```

Comment: but you need to define an array with 7 `null` elements.

Comment: The question stated that the array of `null`s was already defined, if a more general array of n `null`s is needed you could use something like `let days = Array(7).fill(null)`